# How to slow down code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get a task to make this code slower. I can change just inside the method. The reason, why I do this is to try ruby profiling. How or where can I can change a code to make it slower?

```
class FibonacciSequence

  def next_fib
    @index += 1

    if @seq[@index].nil?
      f = @seq[@index - 1] + @seq[@index - 2]
      @seq[@index] = f
      return f
    else
      return @seq[@index]
    end
  end


  def current_fib
    return @index >= 0 ? @seq[@index] : nil
  end

  def current_index
    return @index >= 0 ? @index : nil
  end


  def [](n)
    return nil if n < 0
    return @seq[n] if n <= @index

    while @index < n
      self.next_fib
    end

    return self.current_fib
  end
end
```

Comment: you can use `sleep(num_secs)` to delay the execuation.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried this... Is there another option to change a code to make it slower? I have idea to give there some loops or some unnecessary line od codes...but i am not sure where and how.

Comment: Why do you need to "slow down" your code to profile it? There are specific tools out there to profile code; one of them is: https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof

Comment: adding unnecessary loops or odd code is not a good approach and i will not recommend that.

Comment: because then I compare this code with the slower one to see differences. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sleep(num_secs) is best way.

Other than this is calling function multiple times, itterate through loops, make array/hash  say 1000 elements in it and apply methods like sort, map, on it,
reading remote file, reading huge data and process it (get 1000 users name and convert them all to uppercase. here you can read row in db and update some data clone it and save it back also help, if your db is remote this will give you more lag :)

But sleep is best way as you can comment just 1 line and this code will be optimum or you can change time parameter as you need.